# Is each string decideble?

Tags: turing-machines

Is it possible to prove that there exist for every string a Turing Machine that decides that string?
I think it is provable that for every string you can build a TM that recognises that string, but I cannot find such a TM to decide a string.

Comment: You don't even need a Turing machine, you can use a finite deterministic automaton.

Comment: I suppose you mean finite strings...?

Answer (score 1):

I'll do it in a pseudo-programming-language, recognising the string "1101" as an example.

```
if x1 = 1 then
  if x2 = 1 then
    if x3 = 0 then
      if x4 = 1 then
        return true
return false
```

So by Church's thesis, since I have described how to recognise the string "1101", there is a Turing machine to do it.